# Understanding classes and variables in java

Tags: java, oop

I am new to Java and this was a example I found in the book I am reading.There are several things I do not understand in this code.Please help me to understand it.

```
/*
 * CalculatorModel
 * Encapsilates the data model used by the calculator Application
 */

public class CalculatorModel{
    private double operand1;
    private double operand2;

    public void setOperand1(double value){
        operand1=value;
    }

    public void setOperand2(double value){
        operand2=value;
    }

    public double getOperand1(){
        return operand1;
    }

    public double getOperand2(){
        return operand2;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String s = "operand 1=" + operand1 + "operand 2=" + operand2;
        return s;
    }
}

/*
 * CalculatorHelper
 * A class that performs mathematical functions for a calculator program
 */
public class CalculatorHelper{
    private CalculatorModel calcModel;

    public CalculatorHelper(){
        calcModel=new CalculatorModel();    
    }

    public void setOperand1(double value){
        calcModel.setOperand1(value);
    }

    public void setOperand2(double value){
        calcModel.setOperand2(value);
    }

    public double add(){
        return calcModel.getOperand1()+calcModel.getOperand2();
    }

    public double subtract(){
        return calcModel.getOperand1()-calcModel.getOperand2();
    }

    public double multiply(){
        return calcModel.getOperand1()*calcModel.getOperand2();
    }

    public double divide(){
        return calcModel.getOperand1()/calcModel.getOperand2();
    }
}
```

Please help me to understand what is done by

```
private CalculatorModel calcModel;

    public CalculatorHelper(){
        calcModel=new CalculatorModel();    
    }
```

in the `calculatorHelper` class.  Is `calcModel` a variable a variable of type `CalculatorModel`? What is the difference of having a object as a data type than a primitive data type to a variable?
If calcModel is a variable what is done by the line *calcModel=new                               CalculatorModel();*

I don't understand why it is important to have two classes as `CalculatorModel` and `CalculatorHelper`.

What is done with the method

```
public void setOperand1(double value){
    calcModel.setOperand1(value);
}
```

in the helper class as there's already a `setmethod` in `CalculatorModel` class.

This is what I tried and what's wrong with this code?

```
public class Calculator{
    private double num1,num2;
    public void setValue1(double value1){
        num1=value1;    
    }

    public void setValue2(double value2){
        num2=value2;    
    }

    public double getValue1(){
        return num1;
    }

    public double getValue2(){
        return num2;
    }

    public double add(){
        return getValue1()+getValue2();
    }

    public double subtract(){
        return getValue1()-getValue2();
    }

    public double multiply(){
        return getValue1()*getValue2();
    }

    public double divide(){
        return getValue1()/getValue2();
    }
}
```

Comment: That code does indeed weird things. It's an attempt at object oriented design I can't follow.

Comment: The book should explain it. If it doesn't you could try another (more friendly) book.

Comment: Perhaps a better explanation of OOP is requred: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html

Comment: You're code will run, but your book actually explains that you should separate data (which are managed by CalculatorModel) and data computing (which is done by CalculatorHelper). It is a better way to code, nothing else.

Comment: And there is a lot of debate how to separate what. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model is if I understand that right roughly what happens here.

Comment: @zapl It's a toy example; everything will be anemic. The model could just as easily be a full GUI app that exposes values to the helper, or something that reads equations in from stdin, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "What is the difference of having a object as a data type than a primitive data type to a variable?"

Programming is all about data. Classes you can consider as complex data, and primitives as simple data. Say you have a class `School`

```
public class School {
}
```

What does school have? It has students. You can't represent a student with an of primitive types, because it just doesn't make sense for a student to be a `double`, `int` `boolean`, etc.  So a student is another complex data type, like a school. So in order for the student to be represented as data contained by the school, you need a `Student` class also, which can hold the student's name, address and such

```
public class Student{
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   String address;
   int age;
```

So to fully represent the student being in the school you use the *has-a* relationship, where `School` *has-a* `Student`

```
public class School {
    Student student;
}
```

To delve even deeper, does a school only have *one* student? No, it should have many students. So you would represent that as a `School` having an array of `Students`

```
public class School {
    Student[] students;
}
```

So in terms of data, you have a data tree like this now

```
School
     Student
           firstName
           lastName
           address
           age
     Student
           firstName
           lastName
           address
           age
```

This is the basic idea behind Object Oriented Programming. It's a lot easier to comprehend when you look at objects as actual physical objects. It makes it easier to understand the relationships.

Comment: I felt I was on my sit in my OOP-1 course at university :'). Great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, your assumption that calcModel is a variable object of type CalculatorModel is right. when you say `calcModel = new CalcModel();` it is actually creating another object in memory for storing the data that is to be stored(both operands) and storing the address of that object in calcModel. This way you can refer to object you created earlier. If you have worked with c earlier you can easily say calcModel is a pointer where as the object created is the data in the address located in the pointer.
2. The difference between a primitive type variable and object type variable is that the actual data that is to be stored in the variable is much more complex. For example the class `CalculatorModel` is a combination of two doubles... You can carry both operands as one entity by combining them(encapsulating) in a class. An object may also contain methods that can do some operations on the data stored in its member variables.
3. It is not necessary to have two classes, some people like it that way. I'm positively sure there is no need to create two classes in this case. Both can be merged as you have obviously did. Mind you there are no right and wrong ways to code, some ways of doing it are more preferable because they are more popular and avoids readability issues in long run. `setOperand1()` method is just using `calcModel.setOperand1()` so I don't see a necessity to have it done that way, calcModel.setOperand1 can be called directly from where ever setOperand1() is called. However, there can be case where you want to hide which function of setOperand1 is to be called or some complex operations are to be performed before calling calcModel.setOperand1. In such cases where you want to reduce burden for the callers of calcModel.setOperand1 by created setOperand1().
4. There is nothing wrong with the code. However you don't have to use getValue1() & getValue2() function in your add, subtract and other mathematical operations. you can simply say `return num1+num2` Because, num1 & num2 are member variables of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

```
private CalculatorModel calcModel;

    public CalculatorHelper(){
    calcModel=new CalculatorModel();    
    }
```

> in the calculatorHelper class. Is calcModel a variable a variable of
>   type CalculatorModel ?What is the difference of having a object as a
>   data type than a primitive data type to a variable? If calcModel is a
>   variable what is done by the line calcModel=new CalculatorModel();

The variable `calcModel` is an ***instance*** of `CalculatorModel`, but is a class variable to the class `CalculatorHelper`.  If you want to know about primitive data type vs object data type, [check this article out](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-a-primitive-type-and-a-class-type/).  This line `calcModel=new CalculatorModel();` is ***initializing*** the variable.  You must do this in order to actually use the methods.  [Read more here.](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/javaguide/java/anatomy/creating.html)

> I don't understand why it is important to have two classes as
>   CalculatorModel and CalculatorHelper.

There are cases where helper classes/methods are useful when it comes to separating large chunks of logic.  [Check this article out.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html)

```
public void setOperand1(double value){
        calcModel.setOperand1(value);
    }
```

> in the helper class as there's already a setmethod in CalculatorModel
>   class.

Yes, and it's calling that same exact set method but from the `CalculatorHelper` class.

> This is what I tried and what's wrong with this code?

There seems to be nothing wrong with the code.  I'm assuming you're using it properly from the main method (or whatever method you're using the class in).

Comment: My code works fine.I just needed to know if it was okay to code like that rather than what was given in the book.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a Delegate Pattern by which the author has implemented the `Calculator`. 
The Calculator serves the abstraction of the real-life  Calculator.

By providing the helper/`delegate` class , I separate the behavior of the object.I am free to write my own implementation of add / subtract using a helper class. `Calculator` will serve as the Model of your calculations.

Consider this , If you try to modify the behavior you need to change the whole Calculator class and distribute it to the Client. However , I don't have to modify the Calculator but only the Helper which the client does/might not ship.

There is nothing wrong in what you have done - but consider this - what if you want to have Single instance of the Calculator - you can control `instantion` using helper class (in this case)

Answer (score 0):

```
private CalculatorModel calcModel;

    public CalculatorHelper(){
    calcModel=new CalculatorModel();    
    }
```

is composition which is used here to separate concerns. The `CalculatorHelper`'s concern is to know how to do addition, substraction, .. while the `CalculatorModel` knows the values, how to provide them to the outside and how to store them.

CalculatorHelper`has therefore an instance of`CalculatorModel` to which it can delegate all the things it does not know about. E.g.

```
public void setOperand1(double value){
    calcModel.setOperand1(value);
}
```

The overall design is still questionable. First of all is it a bad encapsulation of a "calculator" because none of math operation reflect back to the model in any way. There needs to be a third class (`CalculatorHelperHelper`?) that knows how to deal with more than two operands.

It is also questionable whether or not a `CalculatorModel` should have two values at once. Two separate value objects would IMO make a lot more sense and would result in more modular code that would also be easier to understand as composition of objects.

The last point in this example is that encapsulating "storage" of values into `CalculatorModel` does not provide any real benefit here. It would if there was some kind of database backend or otherwise "complicated" logic that does not belong into `CalculatorHelper`. I would have taken more or less your approach in a simple real world scenario. Your code is not wrong. It's just a different approach.

The code in the context of the book and given that it is an example to show some design techniques is ok for that purpose. I would just do it very much different if I was to write a calculator. OO design is on the other hand not right or wrong and people can argue a lot about what good design is.